# Cookies are not getting saved in the browser with http header api response

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, http-headers, frontend

I am trying to use cookies to authenticate the user.
from node.js I am sending cookies to my localhost on login with query -

**res.cookie('jwt', generateToken(user), { maxAge: 432000, domain: '.localhost.com', httpOnly: true }**

I have moddified my windos host file to point 127.0.0.1=> test.localhost.com

Now when I login with credentials I get this response header with set-cookie option-

SetCookie:**jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OGUzYTQxNWJmNjczMDBlMjQ1MjQ1YmQiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTE0ODcwMTcsImV4cCI6MTQ5MTQ; Max-Age=432; Domain=.localhost.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 06 Apr 2017 14:04:09 GMT; HttpOnly**

But when I see the cookies in the browser it shows I don`t have any cookies for http://test.localhost.com:3002

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get solution? I am also getting same issue. may you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
res.cookie('jwtToken', token, { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true }); // maxAge: 2 hours
```

It's working for me. Please note that maxAge is in ms.